# Why won't Jquery include classes when elements are created?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a table with just jQuery. The interesting thing is that in the resulting page none of the classes or text are added to the html as they should. The result is I only see the two buttons, but with no text and no background or surroundings like they should. I use similar to produce another element, and that works just fine. I want this particular function to be called when the page first loads, I have a feeling that is where my problem is. Can you explain why?

```
$(function(){
    function create_twitter_bar(){
            var table_container = $("<table/ >", {
                class: "container",
            });
                var row = $("<tr/ >");
                    var menu = $("<td/ >", {
                        class: "menu",
                    });
                        var add_element_button = $("<button/ >", {
                            text: '+',
                            class: "add_button",
                        });
                        var minimize_button = $("<button/ >", {
                            text: 'm',
                            class: "minimize_button",
                        });
                        menu.append(minimize_button);
                        menu.append(add_element_button);
                row.append(menu);
            table_container.append(row);
            $("body").append(table_container);
        }

        create_twitter_bar();
}):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is not with the `class` parameter but with how you call jquery.

```
$("<button/ >", {
  text: '+',
  class: "add_button",
});
```

It's totally fine, but `<button/ >` is not. It should be `<button />`.

This:

```
$("<button />", {
  text: '+',
  class: "add_button",
});
```

Yet `class` is a reserved name now and it should be quoted as a string, yet I'm pretty sure it doesn't really matter because objects in javascript only have strings as key.

Also as we're at it... here one common syntax error that you're going to have on some browsers oh so called IE. In the code above, there is yet still one small syntax error that can be quite dramatic to some versions of IE. I can't tell exactly which but think about it... One second... 4 lines? Really? It's there, but your eyes won't see it. It's so small..... So the error is this, the last `,` in the object definition. It isn't supposed to be valid. You should write your code like this:

```
$("<button />", {
  text: '+',
  class: "add_button"
});
```

Comment: The `class` thing matters on older engines, like IE8.

Comment: @KevinB I don't know, the jquery operator is full of really weird things.

Comment: @KevinB the element get created though but I believe it's like writing `<div>` to create an element should work. But it's possible that the element get created at a different point in time as the syntax wasn't valid and parameters are ignored. I remember I had such kind of problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can believe that, how "semicolons" can totally break IE8-. I'm not so surprised.

Comment: @ Loïc Faure-Lacroix: How exactly can semicolons break IE8? Re `class`, it's entirely understandable if IE8 doen't support ES5's change to the spec, as IE8 **predates** ES5.